# path to public directory bonfire/codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, bonfire

i need verify if one file exist on my controller,

> "localhost/bonfire/application/modules/controllers/controller.php"

but my file path is:

> "localhost/bonfire/public/uploads"

base_url not work, how can I verify that my file exists without relative paths?

Comment: Do you want to check the file exist in upload folder ?

Comment: yep, Is there a function for that? sorry, I do not speak English, this is a translator

Comment: Did you you create new modules?

Comment: are you running apache http server ?what's your virtual host configuration